# Establishing Data Consistency

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a fixed size FIFO type array to store newly added datas. In my main function this array keeps updating itself continuously and one thread working on this data. I want my thread to work on latest passed data to itself meanwhile main function keeps updating it. In the code below, I tried to demonstrate what I am trying to explain. Thread 1 includes a while(1) function itself as well. The reason I am updating Queue on main thread, because Thread 1 has a sleep duration. It may has a simple answer, however my brain currently stopped working.

```
int main(){
pthread_create(Thread1);
while(1) {
QueuePut(Some_Value);
arguments_of_Thread1.input = Queue;
...
}
return 0;
```

Comment: If "Thread 1" doesn't need to update the shared array then why not take a copy and let it use it?

Comment: @P.P. Do you mean I should copy it to another array in Thread 1 function as soon as I pass it?

Comment: Yes. But in case case, "meanwhile main function keeps updating it" is confusing. If 2 threads can operate on independent data, you won't need any "Data Consistency" as you put it. If they operate on the same data, you do need have synchronization and in that case "I want my thread to work on latest passed data to itself" is contradictory.